# WPF: How to apply a controlTemplate to a TabControl's tabItem Header while using Databinding?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, controltemplate, tabitem

I have a TabControl which is acquiring tabs and content through DataBinding. Instead of normal Tabs, I wanted Tabs to be of custom shape (say, Ellipse) for all tabs, So I have a ControlTemplate which i want to apply for all tabs.Being new to WPF,I am just confused on how to apply a controlTemplate to a TabControl's tabItem  header while using Databinding?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="TabItemControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <Border CornerRadius="12" x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
               <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
            </Border>
        </Grid>

    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
     <TabControl
    ItemsSource="{Binding CarCollection}">
                <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <!-- this is the header template-->
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock
                Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                    <!-- this is the body of the TabItem template-->
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentControl
                Content="{Binding Value}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

In those cases where databinding is not used, I know how to apply it. Issue is when Databinding is used, I am able to achieve this through the below code.

```
<TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="224" Margin="72,66,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="412">
        <TabItem Header="TabItem" Template="{DynamicResource TabItemControlTemplate1}" Height="19.96" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="TabItem">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

Any help on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `Style` to set `Template` of `TabItem` generated from binding :

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding CarCollection}">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource TabItemControlTemplate1}"/>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <!-- this is the header template-->
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <!-- this is the body of the TabItem template-->
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Value}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: the XAML looks queer: you're setting TabItem's template to `{DynamicResource TabItemControlTemplate1}` and using `TabControl.ContentTemplate` for tab items. Won't they conflict?